# Is the minimum and maximum of the function $w = y$ constrained by $x^2+y^2+z^2 =1$ equal to $\pm 1$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

This is a problem on www.mitcourseware.com , multivariable calculus 18.02, Session 39 on Lagrange Multipliers. Not a homework problem This is a self tutorial course  , brushing up on multivariable calculus.  I can pretty much jot the problem below with a quick summary.

The function is $w = y$ and it is constrained by $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 =1$.  I got some of it...the gradient of $f = \langle 0,1,0\rangle$ and the gradient of $g = \langle 2x, 2y, 2z\rangle$ taking the partial derivatives then we see the gradient of $f$  is equal to $\lambda$ times the gradient of $g$, therefore very simply $\langle 0,1,0\rangle= \lambda\times\langle 2x, 2y, 2z\rangle$ , obviously $x = z =0$ but I get $2y = 1$ or $y = \frac12$ BUT the listed answer is $\pm 1$ for the maximum and minimum respectively.  I can't see how this can be.

Need some help from an expert. Thank you.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: the Minimum is $-1$ and will attained for $$x=0,y=-1,z=0$$

Comment: Actually you get $ 2 \lambda y = 1 $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake comes from the fact you forgot about the Lagrange multiplier when you solved for $y$. Starting with the Lagrangian:
$$L(x,y,z,\lambda)=f(x,y,z)-\lambda g(x,y,z)$$
$$L(x,y,z)=y-\lambda (x^2+y^2+z^2-1)$$
The optimality conditions here require $\nabla_{x,y,z,\lambda} L(x,y,z,\lambda)=0$, as you correctly recognized:
$$\nabla L(x,y,z,\lambda)=(-2\lambda x,\  1-2\lambda y,\  -2\lambda z,\  \ x^2+y^2+z^2-1)$$
Setting this equal to zero tells us that either $\lambda=0$ or $x=0$, $y=\frac{1}{2\lambda}$, and $\lambda=0$ or $z=0$. Clearly if $\lambda=0$, $y$ is undefined, so $x=0$ and $z=0$. 
The part you ultimately forgot is plugging in the Lagrange multiplier into the constraint equation:
$$x^2+y^2+z^2-1=0$$
Substituting our known values for $x$ and $z$ and the expression for $y$, we get
$$\frac{1}{4\lambda^2}=1$$
Therefore $\lambda=\pm\frac{1}{2}$ and substituting this into the $y$ equation shows $y=\frac{1}{2(\pm\frac{1}{2})}=\pm 1$, as desired.

Comment: Wikipedia does a pretty good job with lagrange multipliers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier, and the slightly more advanced but conceptually identical KKT conditions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions

Comment: I feel embarrassed about this ....sorry.  I sure enough did forget lamda.....